# pointcut for inherited methods

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

How can I match all methods available for a specific class?

For example I have following class hierarachy

```
      A
    / | \
   B  C  D
  /   |   \
 E    F    I
      |
      T
```

I need to match all methods that are available in `T`, so these are methods defined in `T` itself and also inherited methods from classes `A`, `C`, `F`.

I came to following pointcut, but not quite happy with that because it matches lots of other classes not related to `T`:

```
execution(* A+.*(..)) && this(T)
```

As I understand with such pointcut aspectj will modify each method defined in classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `I`, `T`. I would like not to affect classes out of `T` family. It would be ideally if only `T` is affected (inherited methods are overridden with aspectj code). There are lots of classes and I want to minimize impact on the rest of system, i.e. I need to modify behavior only of class `T` and do not want these modification to affect other classes.

I could rewrite pointcut to following: `(execution(* A.*(..)) || execution(* C.*(..)) || ... <all parent classes>) && this(T)`. But this makes me to make sure that hierarchy is correct and update it whenever actual hierarchy changes.

Thanks.

Comment: why you do not try such think p(T as t): (execution T.*(..)) && this(t); or have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, I just tried and investigated the byte code. The advice will only be woven into A, C, F, T because `this()` can be determined statically during compile time.

**Update:** I forgot to mention that your pointcut only matches methods derived from A and its subclasses. If you, as you say in the headline, really want to match all inherited methods, use `execution(* *(..)) && this(T)`.