# AspectJ on children objects

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm starting to work with AspectJ and I'm trying to do something that I don't know if it's possible. This is my code:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractObject<T> {
    private T myOtherObject;

    public T getMyOtherObject() {
        return myOtherObject;
    }
}

@Component
public class MyObject extends MyAbstractObject<WhateverObject> {
    
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspects {
    
    @Before("execution(* mypackage.MyAbstractObject.getMyOtherObject().set*(*))")
    public void beforeExample(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // DO THINGS
    }
}
```

This code fails, with the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting ')' at character position 58 execution(* mypackage.MyAbstractObject.getMyOtherObject().set*(*))
```

However, I can intercept MyOtherObject like this, but not it's setters:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspects {
    
    @Before("execution(* mypackage.MyAbstractObject.getMyOtherObject())")
    public void beforeExample(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        // DO THINGS
    }
}
```

I don't want to intercept the setters of the object MyOtherObject everywhere, because this object is used in more places in the program where I don't need aspects. However I want to intercept them only when used in a class that extends MyAbstractObject.

I'm using Spring with AspectJ.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199222/pointcut-for-inherited-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you just invented is illegal, unfortunately. You cannot describe chained method calls the ways you dreamed up.

What you really want is to intercept method executions of type `WhateverObject`, not of `MyAbstractObject` or `MyObject`. I.e., your pointcut should rather bet something like

```java
execution(* mypackage.WhateverObject.set*(*))
```

I am just guessing, but if you want to limit matching to control flows where the setter method is called (directly or indirectly) from `getMyOtherObject()`, in AspectJ your would add something like

```java
&& cflow(execution(* mypackage.MyAbstractObject.getMyOtherObject()))
```

to the first pointcut. But `cflow` pointcuts are unavailable in Spring AOP, which is what you seem to be using. So

- either you switch to native AspectJ, which is easy to [integrate into Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) applications, but can also be used outside of the Spring context because it is an idependent product,
- or you check if Spring AOP's ["lite" version of control flow pointcuts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-api-pointcuts-cflow) does what you need. I posted a few answers and links mentioning this almost undocumented feature [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69567232/1082681) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66649082/1082681).

As a native AspectJ fan who does not normally use Spring, you can imagine which option I would recommend regarding control flow pointcuts, but I think you can make your own decision.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it was very clear and useful. I'm actually looking for the second solution, so I'm going to switch to AspectJ and take a look to `cflow` as you suggested.